# What does “jenste” mean?

Tags: meaning, etymology, swiss-german

I read *jenste* occasionally in Swiss newspapers, which is consistent with the fact that dict.cc [classifies the word as *schweiz.*](http://www.dict.cc/?s=jenste)

I see that it means “many” but is there more to it? Does it have a nuance? Also: What is its etymological background?

Comment: Please give us some context. Post some sentences where you found this word.

Comment: Definitely Swiss, and unlikely to be understood in Germany. Not recorded in the _Variantenwörterbuch_, hence probably considered nonstandard in Switzerland, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ich hoffe es ist in Ordnung wenn ich auf Deutsch antworte.

Da mir das Wort bisher nicht geläufig war, habe ich danach gesucht, und es gefunden:

> Als Kind lernte ich **jenste** Deiner Sketche auswendig und mein Lachen über Deine Auftritte hat mein Leben sehr bereichtert!

<sup>Nachruf auf einen verstorbenen Schauspieler</sup>

> Die *BBinsektenschutz Anstalt* bietet **jenste** Formen von Insektenschutzvorrichtungen an.

<sup>Werbetext</sup>

> **Jenste** Kleider/Schuhe. Preis Verhandelbar.

<sup>Text auf einem Webshop</sup>

> Die Hälfte der Ware in der Verpackung benötige ich zwar nicht, so z.B. den Splitter, **jenste** Kabel, Anleitungen und sogar einen schönen Bluewin-Kugelschreiber haben sie da reingepackt.

<sup>Erfahrungsbericht</sup>

Mir war zunächst unklar, ob »jenste« ein Wort des Schweizerischen Deutsch oder des Schweizerdeutsch ist. Ersteres ist eine der drei standardisierten Variationen der Deutschen Sprache, letzteres ist eine Gruppe von Dialekten.

Da das Wort in einer Zeitung entdeckt wurde, und ich es, als ich danach gegoogelt habe, ausschließlich in Standarddeutschen Texten gefunden habe (siehe oben), gehe ich davon aus, dass »jenste« kein Dialektwort ist, sondern zum Vokabular des Schweizerischen Standards der Deutschen Sprache gehört.

Auch die Bedeutung und in weiter Folge die Herkunft werden durch die Fundstellen klar:

> jenste = jede Menge

Das Wort ist also eine Verkürzung einer gängigen Phrase. Allerdings kann ich nicht erklären, wie das s in das Wort gekommen ist.

Die Phrase »jede Menge« wird, wie ich glaube, im ganzen deutschen Sprachraum verstanden. Sie ist ein Synonym für »sehr viel«.

Comment: Die Etymologie erscheint mir spekulativ.

Comment: Vielleicht verwandt, analog zu 'jegliche (-es, -er)' ('jeglicher Sketch, 'jegliche Formen von Insekten, jegliche Kleider und Schuhe, jegliche Kabel', 'jegliches Gebäck').

Comment: Für mich sieht das eigentlich stark nach dem Superlativ von *jene* aus. Im [Schweizerischen Idiotikon](https://idiotikon.ch/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=259&Itemid=197) gibt es unter dem Eintrag *jëneʳ* auch eine Bedeutung (groß, ungeheuer), die ansatzweise in diese Richtung geht und förmlich nach einem Superlativ verlangt. Allerdings gibt es *jenste* wohl noch nicht lang genug für das Wörterbuch. (Die Quellen wurden im 19. Jh. gesammelt.)

Comment: Das Dialektwort, zumindest im berndeutschen Sprachraum, hat eine Annotation von "entfernt", "alles mögliche". Z.B. _jenste Verwandte_ = "auch weit entfernte Verwandte". Dies könnte ein möglicher Hinweis auf die genannte Verbindung zu _jene_ sein.

Answer (score 1):

Jenste means a lot of something
Jenste bedeutet sehr viel von etwas

Comment: Welcome to German SE! The question already says that it means "many". Are you Swiss or live in Switzerland and know the word from own use? Did you find it in a dictionary? It's unclear what information you're trying to add, maybe you could edit the answer to specify why you know.

Answer (score 1):

Jenste im Schweizerdeutschen Sprachgebrauch meint "viele, aber doch unterschiedliche".

Also z.B. "Jenste Händler auf dem Markt" bedeutet hier: viele Händler mit unterschiedlichen Waren auf dem Markt.
Weiter oben wurden jenste Sketche erwähnt, die nachgespielt wurden, also viele deiner Sketche aber doch ist jeder Sketch an sich anders.
Oder jenste Kabel, da sind viele Kabel aber doch unterschiedliche Kabel in der Verpackung drin.

Eine Menge (Händler / Sketche / Kabel), die eine Gemeinsamkeit hat und doch unterschiedlich ist.

Somit hat "jenste" in der Ausgangsfrage tatsächlich noch eine zusätzliche Nuance.